# Get all user from SharePoint group using SharePoint Designer workflow 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, web-services, web

I have a user group on my SharePoint Online site. The name of group is "Programmer".

Now I want to retrieve all the user from "Programmer" using SharePoint Designer workflow. How could I call webservice for getting appropriate output ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an HTTP web service call to return the users.

```
http://site/_api/web/sitegroups/GetByName('Programmer')/users
```